# Does either Rackspace or AWS provide APIs for billing information?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud-computing, cloud-hosting, rackspace-cloud

By billing, I mean real-time usage and consumption statistics - the API for which can be used to generate custom reports, forecast expenditure, etc.

I see that AWS has the facility to generate custom reports pertaining to usage that they export as a CSV from [this page](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37918435/aws.PNG).

Do they also provide an API **for the same** where the user can generate reports / play around with the billing/usage data?

What about Rackspace? I see that they introduced this tool called [Cloudability](https://cloudability.com/features/) which monitors usage from SEVERAL cloud providers. *I wonder how they are able to extract such information from such a large number of providers?* Can anyone explain that? *Is API the only route?*

Comment: The CloudWatch API can [give you](http://www.quora.com/Amazon-Web-Services/Does-Amazon-provide-an-API-for-pulling-AWS-account-usage-details) live billing information in AWS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I monitor daily spending on AWS?](http://serverfault.com/questions/350971/how-can-i-monitor-daily-spending-on-aws)

Comment: What about Rackspace? Any comments on how Cloudability works?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from one of [Cloudability](https://cloudability.com/)'s public [support pages](http://support.cloudability.com/customer/portal/questions/674679-rackspace-usage-information):

> ... there is no API for that information so today we have to collect the
>   information by **scraping the billing/invoice pages** via the **Rackspace
>   portal**, hence the need for the credential. We're working with
>   Rackspace on a better way to access the data but for the time being
>   that is the only option.

Comment: Any update on this in the past two years? I really don't want to scrape the rackspace portal

Comment: The value add of Cloudability is that _you_ don't scrape the portal -- _they do_. It's a little better now than when Cloudability was first introduced. You used to have to give them the admin credentials for your whole cloud account. Not cool, because what's to stop them from launching a dozen servers? But then Rackspace Cloud added better security granularity. You can now create a "Billing Only" user and give those credentials to Cloudability, instead.

Comment: That doesn't help me when I am trying to aggregate data from multiple cloud platforms including Rackspace so I guess the answer is there is still no AP I have to scrape the page myself

Comment: Or does cloudability have an API

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace AFAIK does not give you access to billing information via API but Amazon has it's http://aws.amazon.com/devpay/ that developers can use to build billing system for billing the customers. I think it may be relevant to your interests.

Comment: how about Cloudability? Where does it fetch all the information from? Currently it supports ~15 providers. Any idea?